# How Can I add cart icon on the nav-menu in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

[image]

I've noticed that almost all online stores include cart icon on the right side of nav-bar. I want to know if there is a way to add cart icon on the right-side of nav-bar like it's shown in the image. I am using WooCommerce.

Comment: I believe most woocommerce-ready themes has something that's at least similar to that built in from the start? WooCommerce's standard theme, Storefront, for example also has something similar - you can see the theme here: https://demo.woothemes.com/storefront/

Comment: We are developing our own theme that is why I asked this question.

Comment: Alright - may I suggest you include that information from the start then and clarify your question with what you want and how you expect to get it. Otherwise it's useless trying to help as we can't know what you want to achieve. Also, what have you tried so far? Provide some code example

Answer (score 2):

Use the Woocomerce mini cart.

Example for a mini cart:

```
/* Custom Shoping Cart in the top */
function YOURTHEME_wc_print_mini_cart() {
    ?>
    <div id="YOURTHEME-minicart-top">
        <?php if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) : ?>
            <ul class="YOURTHEME-minicart-top-products">
                <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) :
                $_product = $cart_item['data'];
                // Only display if allowed
                if ( ! apply_filters('woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) || ! $_product->exists() || $cart_item['quantity'] == 0 ) continue;
                // Get price
                $product_price = get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_cart' ) == 'excl' ? $_product->get_price_excluding_tax() : $_product->get_price_including_tax();
                $product_price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price_html', woocommerce_price( $product_price ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                ?>
                <li class="YOURTHEME-mini-cart-product clearfix">
                    <span class="YOURTHEME-mini-cart-thumbnail">
                        <?php echo $_product->get_image(); ?>
                    </span>
                    <span class="YOURTHEME-mini-cart-info">
                        <a class="YOURTHEME-mini-cart-title" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $cart_item['product_id'] ); ?>">
                            <h4><?php echo apply_filters('woocommerce_widget_cart_product_title', $_product->get_title(), $_product ); ?></h4>
                        </a>
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_price', '<span class="woffice-mini-cart-price">' . __('Unit Price', 'YOURTHEME') . ':' . $product_price . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="YOURTHEME-mini-cart-quantity">' . __('Quantity', 'woffice') . ':' . $cart_item['quantity'] . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                    </span>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul><!-- end .YOURTHEME-mini-cart-products -->
        <?php else : ?>
            <p class="YOURTHEME-mini-cart-product-empty"><?php _e( 'No products in the cart.', 'YOURTHEME' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart()) > 0) : ?>
            <h4 class="text-center YOURTHEME-mini-cart-subtotal"><?php _e( 'Cart Subtotal', 'YOURTHEME' ); ?>: <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></h4>
            <div class="text-center">
                <a href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" class="cart btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <?php _e( 'Cart', 'YOURTHEME' ); ?>
                </a>
                <a href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_checkout_url(); ?>" class="alt checkout btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> <?php _e( 'Checkout', 'YOURTHEME' ); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Hook it on the place you want...

To show ajax total price use this:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/

Comment: I'd recommend using a plugin if you just want a simple cart icon https://wordpress.org/plugins/bc-menu-cart-woo/